# How to convert raw CAN data to human readable format using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode, can-bus, decoder

The sample data is given here      .
`0.005225 1  282        Rx D 8  00  00  FF  F5  FF  FF  14  01` I know the meaning of each byte and its unit. I want to decode this data into human readable format, such as CAN ID description, value with or without units. How to do it in python? Any libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `python-can` python package? It also has a `Message` object where you can initiate the `Message` object from a `bytearray`.